# $cf(\aleph_{\alpha}) = cf(\alpha)$ for all limit ordinals $\alpha$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I am trying to prove the following Lemma:

> Lemma: Let $\alpha$ be a limit ordinal. Then $cf(\aleph_{\alpha}) = cf(\alpha)$.

I am using the following definitions:

> Definition: Let $(\mathbb{P}, \preceq)$ be a partially ordered set. A subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{P}$ is said to be cofinal if for all $p \in \mathbb{P}$ there exists $q \in A$ such that $p \preceq q$.

> Definition: Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal. The cofinality of $\alpha$ is the least ordinal $\lambda$ such that there exists a function $f: \lambda \to \alpha$ whose range is cofinal in $(\alpha, \leq)$. We denote the cofinality of $\alpha$ by $cf(\alpha)$.

There is also a useful lemma:

> Lemma: Let $\alpha$ be a non-zero ordinal number. Then there exists a strictly increasing function $f: cf(\alpha) \to \alpha$ whose range is cofinal in $(\alpha,\leq)$.

My idea is to prove the lemma in question is to prove that $cf(\aleph_{\alpha}) \leq cf(\alpha)$ and $cf(\alpha) \leq cf(\aleph_{\alpha})$. My idea for the first inequality is as follows:

Proof idea: Let $f: cf(\alpha) \to \alpha$ be a strictly increasing function such that $ran(f)$ is cofinal in $(\alpha,\leq)$. Consider the function $g: \alpha \to \aleph_{\alpha}$ such that $g(\theta)=\aleph_{\theta}$ for all $\theta \in \alpha$.

If I can show that the range of $g \circ f: cf(\alpha) \to \aleph_{\alpha}$ is cofinal in $(\aleph_{\alpha},\leq)$, then $cf(\aleph_{\alpha}) \leq cf(\alpha)$.

Let $p \in \aleph_{\alpha}$. How can I show that there is $q \in ran(g \circ f)$ such that $p \leq q$?

Thank you!

Comment: $p\le \aleph_\gamma$ for some $\gamma<\alpha$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for your comment. So, there exists $\theta \in cf(\alpha)$ such that $f(\theta) \geq \gamma$ for any $\gamma \in \alpha$ by definition of $f$. Thus, $\aleph_{f(\theta)} \geq \aleph_{\gamma} \geq p$, correct? But why does such $\gamma$ exist? Could you please explain this in more detail?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The definition of $\aleph_\alpha$ for limit $\alpha$ is $\bigcup_{\gamma<\alpha}\aleph_\gamma.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks, I have also given it another thought and it actually follows from the definition. If $\aleph_{\gamma} < p$ for all $\gamma < \alpha$, then $\aleph_{\alpha}=sup${$\aleph_{\gamma}: \gamma < \alpha$}$ \leq p$, which contradicts $p \in \aleph_{\alpha}$.